# drag external element on existing event - fullcalendar - angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I need to drag an external element (a `<div>`) onto an existing event on the calendar (it mustn't create a new event but should modify an existing, I should apply a custom render or change the look of the existing event)

I'm able to drag  an external element  into the calendar in order to generate a new event, but not to modify an existing one

Here is a stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo

How may I get a reference of the existing event I drop on?
I'm using the angular wrapper of fullcalendar, any idea?

Comment: AFAIK fullCalendar does not support this. You'd probably have to write some completely custom code and patch the main library

Comment: And what about this: How may I get a reference of the existing event I drop on?

Comment: That's the thing I am saying is not supported. There is no way to achieve it. The whole "external events" feature is designed on the assumption that you want to add new events, not update or replace an existing one. There is just no mechanism to do what you're asking. Hence why I said you would have to code it yourself. And it would probably be quite a big complicated change

Answer (score 0):

Since version 6.0.0 of Angular/FullCalendar you can do it by providing #eventContent (through content projection) and, for example, using angular cdk drag and drop

```
<ng-template #eventContent>
 <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"></div>
</ng-template>
```

the element you're going to drop should have cdkDrag directive applied and to be in cdkDropList, and both cdkDropList should be enclosed by cdkDropListGroup.

If this answer was useful, please, accept it, so other people could see it, thanks.